# Methods in Enums

Tags: java, function, methods, enums

So I am confused on if in Java enums can have functions. I am making a simple html editor and wanted to use enums to represent the html tags, yes I know this is not the best way to go about it but its the way my group decided to implement it.

So I have been trying to do something like this, but when I try to call `TagEnums.normalTags()` it suggests making it a static method, I guess I am wondering if this is right or if there is a better way to implement it instead of making public `ArrayList<String> normalTags()` into `public static ArrayList<String> normalTags()`

```
public enum TagEnum {
    H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, P, B, I, U, BR, HR, RP, RT, RUBY

    public ArrayList<String> normalTags(){
        String normalTags = "H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, P, B, I, U";
        ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Enum<?> currentEnum: TagEnum.values()){
            if(normalTags.contains(currentEnum.toString())){
               tags.add("<"+currentEnum.toString().toLowerCase()+">");
               tags.add("</"+currentEnum.toString().toLowerCase()+">");
            }
        }
        return tags;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fine the way it is :) when you say "it suggests" I'm guessing Eclipse. Eclipse's suggestions are sometimes good, other times stupid. Good thing you decided to ask!

Comment: You can even make abstract methods and override them for each enum! See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850842/overriding-abstract-method-or-using-one-single-method-in-enums

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I think that suggestion makes sense - the method's implementation isn't specific to a particular enum constant. It's doing something statically, using all the enum values.

Comment: Also I think there needs to be a `;` after `RUBY` for it to even compile.

Comment: @PaulBellora I just noticed that and fixed that thanks though! and I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't an easier/better way to do it, Thanks!

Comment: @PaulBellora didn't notice that. Good eyesight!

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn yeah I am using Eclipse and I know it occasionally makes bad suggestions and I was hesitant because I have not used enums before this project

Comment: BTW, your `normalTags` method should be **`static`** because it is not related to an instance of the type.

Comment: @AlvinWong that was part of the question that I was trying to ask was if it should be static or not and if there way a better way to implement it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Java enums can have functions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Example from this page:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Planet <earth_weight>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        double earthWeight = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double mass = earthWeight/EARTH.surfaceGravity();
        for (Planet p : Planet.values())
           System.out.printf("Your weight on %s is %f%n",
                             p, p.surfaceWeight(mass));
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this online but was unsure if another class needing access if it needed to be public methods instead of private

Comment: @Tall Paul Methods should be private if they are internal methods that are details of implementation, not details of contract/what the object is FOR from the perspective of users of the object. Methods should be public if they define what the object is used FOR/what you ask it about.